# How to change text color when Button/TextView is pressed in android

Tags: android, xml

How can i change TextView text color by using custom xml file.
When i press the button button text should change into white color, When i release the button the text should be changed into black color. Because i have used this background.xml for all textviews. so if i change in single place it will be affect all the place. but Text Color is not changing.

TextView Code i used :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_add"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/student_name"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="18dp" />
```

background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <item 
         android:drawable="@drawable/bg1"
         android:color="@color/White" 
         android:state_pressed="false"/>

     <item 
         android:drawable="@drawable/bg2"
         android:color="@color/black"  
         android:state_pressed="true"/>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

TextView

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_add"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/student_name"
    android:textColor="@drawable/my_text_color"
    android:textSize="18dp" />
```

drawable/my_text_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/White"/>
    <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/White"/>
    <!-- activated -->
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@color/White"/>
    <!-- checked -->
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/White"/>

    <!-- default -->
    <item android:color="@color/black"/>

</selector>
```

In your class file add the following code,

```
textView.setselected(true);
```

Comment: @Vignesh KM, please notify me if this code is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

[Sagar Zala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3235048/sagar-zala)
The Code you have given is working. I used like this.

TextView Code :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_add"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/blood_pressure"
    android:textColor="@drawable/my_text_color"
    android:textSize="18dp" />
```

background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <item 
         android:drawable="@drawable/bg1"
         android:state_pressed="false"/>

     <item 
         android:drawable="@drawable/bg2"
         android:state_pressed="true"/>

</selector>
```

my_text_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/White"/>
    <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/White"/>
    <!-- activated -->
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@color/White"/>
    <!-- checked -->
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/White"/>

    <!-- default -->
    <item android:color="@color/black"/>

</selector>
```